# Convert currency after "Place Order" clicked

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, currency

I'd like to convert all items price on cart from USD to another currency before it saved into a order (post). Could someone tell me what woocommerce hook that possible to do that please? With example would be better.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order' hook can be used in your case.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'asdf_alter_price', 10, 1 );
function asdf_alter_price ($order) {

    // do the conversion - you can do this however you want
    $new_price = convert_to_galactic_credits($order->get_total());

    $order->set_total( $new_price );

  }

  return $order;

}
```